# Can't push to heroku (will not compile ruby app)

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

When I do "git push heroku master", I get this error at the end of the log.

```
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to johnz-project.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/johnz-project.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) 
 error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/johnz-project.git'
```

Also somewhere up in the log, I saw this:

```
Can't find file jquery-ui/effect-blind
```

Don't know why cos I added the jquery-ui-rails gem to my gemfile and it works in the app in development.

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui/effect-blind
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require lightbox-bootstrap
//= require custom
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

application.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "lightbox-bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "jquery-ui";
```

Please help!

edit:

after doing "heroku run rake db:migrate" i got this error somewhere in the stacktrace:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "categories" does not exist: 
CREATE TABLE "products" ("id" serial primary key, "title" character varying, 
"description" character varying, "category_id" integer, "picture" character varying, "video" character varying, "created_at"       
timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_fb915499a4"                                                           
FOREIGN KEY ("category_id") REFERENCES "categories" ("id"))
```

edit:

should i do it like this:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.postgresql
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you assets are not compile on heroku.

Follow below code:

## config/environments/production.rb

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

then run commands:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

then push all compiled files with menifest file to heroku.

Comment: i got this error after the second command:   Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery' with type 'application/javascript'

Comment: Put gem 'jquery-rails', "~> 2.3.0" into Gemfile. Run `bundle install` and push to heroku

Comment: Make sure `//= require jquery-ui` is in application.js

Comment: after bundle install, i got this error: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
In Gemfile: jquery-rails (~> 2.3.0) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 2.3.0, which depends on railties (< 5.0, >= 3.0) x86-mingw32

    rails (~> 5.0.2) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on railties (= 5.0.2) x86-mingw32

Comment: add `gem  'jquery-rails'` and run bundle

Comment: Yes...accept and vote my answer if it works for you. Thanks

Comment: you have to run migrations also on heroku...command `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: is the migration runs properly on your local machine?

Comment: part of the output is what is above

Comment: the rest is just stacktrace jargons

Comment: migration runs well in development

Comment: try to run following commands on local. 1. `rake db:drop` 2. `rake db:create` 3. `rake db:migrate` and check if you get the error or not on local machine

Comment: after "rake db:drop", i got error: Permission denied @ unlink_internal - C:/Sites/project/db/development.sqlite3
Couldn't drop database 'db/development.sqlite3'
rails aborted!
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ unlink_internal - C:/Sites/project/db/develop
ment.sqlite3

Comment: have you used `sqlite` db on heroku?

Comment: i am on windows machine

Comment: have you used sqlite db on heroku?

Comment: change database_name in database.yml and then run `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate`

Comment: no..do this in local machine...I think the problem is with your migrations files

Comment: sounder development i should change from sqlite3 to postgrsql

Comment: so under i should change from sqlite3 to postgrsql

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146428/discussion-between-johnnydevv-and-puneet18).